# cannot share facebook video link from php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is a rather strange issue..
I am not able to publish a facebook video link on my wall.

The following code works perfectly fine...

```
$attachment = array(
  'link' => "www.google.com"
);
$publish = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```

But the following code doesnt

```
$attachment = array(
  'link' => "http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150238694155484"
);
$publish = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```

It doesn't post anything to my wall.

Has anyone seen the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, facebook made the picture parameter required for video links

Comment: not really.. it works fine for youtube and dailymotion videos.. problem is only with facebook videos.. but yeah there is definitely something related to the picture property.. i gave some dummy value for the picture property and the post went through

Comment: @contacthima maybe it's "required" for urls that have no og:image property. Which is a strange way to enforce requirement

Answer (score 0):

Add it into try catch

```
try{
    $attachment = array(
         'link' => "http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150238694155484"
    );
    $publish = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

it will show you all error details needed to resolve your problem